# how to set .NET win app controls size properties to have same looking on different systems?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows

hi i have developed a windows forms  application and I deployed it and I installed It on another system with different screen reselution and some of my controls don't look as they did on my own system for example I have lables in a groupbox and in the target machin they have exceeded the bounderies of the group box ! I want to know how should I exactly set different size properties of different controls to have same looking on different systems with different reselutions and different screen inches ?!

thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: You're talking about DPI, not resolution.

Comment: @SLaks ok ,thx , what should I do ?

Comment: I assume you're using WinForms?

Comment: Winforms or WPF or OOB Silverlight?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't properly anchor your controls within your form.

Comment: @Menefee what should I do , could you explain me ?

Comment: Sound like your labels are on top of or underneath the groupbox as opposed to being inside it. Cut one of the offenders off the form, select the group box and then paste.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF); if so, you will need to set a Grid inside of your GroupBox control.  If you are used to HTML you can think of the Grid as being something like a table.  Then arrainge your Labels or other controls within the Grid.  Below is an example and be sure to note the Margin tags.  They are what positions the control within the Grid.

```
<GroupBox Header="groupBox1" Height="135" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,78,0,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,28,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

To do the same in Windows Forms you would need to manually add the control to the GroupBox.

```
gbCtrl = new GroupBox();
gbCtrl.Left   = 20; // <- These are relative to the main form.
gbCtrl.Top    = 20;
gbCtrl.Width  = 120;
gbCtrl.Height = 60;
gbCtrl.Text = "Sample GroupBox";

Button btnSample = new Button();
btnSample .Left = 22; // <- These are relative to the groupbox
btnSample .Top  = 24; // 
gbCtrl.Controls.Add(btnSample); // <- Add the button to the groupbox

Controls.Add(gbCtrl); // <- Add the groupbox to the main form.
```

Comment: thx for yoyr reply but I am not using WPF , I am using windows forms apllication

Comment: @Karamafrooz My guess is that you have not added your label controls belong to the main form and not the groupbox control.  See my edited post above.